# Hazard model for three-tiered-response dependent variable

Tags: statistical-significance, survival, cox-model, hazard

My time-series dataset is composed of measurements for a number of independent variables and one dependent variable. The dependent variable accepts 3 responses: weak reaction, strong reaction, or no reaction. The objects in the dataset can take no reaction, weak reaction, strong reaction, or both weak and strong reactions. An object that takes both reactions may do so in any of the two orders: weak-strong and strong-weak.

I'd like to see if there is an association between the independent variables and the dependent variable using a hazard model, but I don't know how to model the reactions because of the peculiarities described above.